# How to tell what frame you're on in ActionScript 2.0

Tags: flash, frame, preloader

How do I tell what frame I'm on in a movie clip? For instance I want have a preloader set up so that the animation of the preloader plays all the way without jumping around. according to the bytes loaded. Here's the basic gist of what I want to happen:

```
bytes_loaded = math.round(this.getBytesLoaded());
bytes_total = math.round(this.getBytesTotal());
getPercent = bytes_loaded/bytes_total;

if (loader_mc.currentFrame < getPercent*100)
    {
        loader_mc.play();
    }
else
    {
        loader_mc.stop();
    }
```

no matter where I look I can't find how to do this... or even if you can. I know I could make a variable that changed on each frame, but that would be dang annoying and tedious to set up... is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    trace( loader_mc.currentFrame );
}
```

it may also be `loader_mc._currentFrame` I don't remember which